# jwplayer 7 and iPhone 4 - media not playing

Tags: iphone, html, jwplayer

on iPhone 4 jwplayer is showing a black screen. on iPhone 6 you can see a black screen with a play button and the video is playing.

```
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "file.mp4",
        'autostart': 'true',
        'width':'100%',
        'aspectratio': '16:9',
        skin: {
          name: "five"
        },
        tracks: [{
          file: 'file.vtt',
          kind: 'thumbnails'
        }]
    });
```

jwplayer 6 worked, after update to 7 it doesn't work anymore on iPhone 4

Comment: Are you on iOS 7 or iOS8?

Comment: 7.1.2 ... with jwplayer 6 it worked

Comment: Ah yes, this is a known issue with JW Player 7.0.0 player. We are planning on addressing it for a future release though.